# Xpath Nokogiri Nested

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm doing some work with a large XML document for an affiliate program that contains product information for computer games. An example of the entires are shown below.

```
<prod id="743854322">
    <pId>GS811CF</pId>
    <text>
        <name>Tour De France 2013</name>
        <desc>Platform: XBOX 360  Publisher: FOCUS HOME INTER  Genre: SPORTS  Supported Languages: English</desc>
    </text>
    <uri>
        <awTrack>http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=743854322&amp;a=161542&amp;m=3026</awTrack>
        <awImage>http://images.productserve.com/preview/3026/743854322.jpg</awImage>
        <mLink>http://tracking.searchmarketing.com/click.asp?aid=520005430000038657</mLink>
        <mImage>http://images2.drct2u.com/content/images/products/gs/gs811/gs811_xb2to52.jpg</mImage>
    </uri>
    <price curr="GBP">
        <buynow>47.00</buynow>
        <delivery>3.99</delivery>
    </price>
    <cat>
        <awCatId>579</awCatId>
        <awCat>Video Games</awCat><mCat>Main Menu|Electricals|Gaming &amp;amp; Consoles|Video Games</mCat>
    </cat>
    <brand>
        <awBrandId>427</awBrandId>
        <brandName>Xbox 360</brandName>
    </brand>
</prod>
```

I'd like to be able to search this document for a computer game name that equals "Tour De France 2013" and is also on the xbox "Platform: XBOX 360".

I've tried a couple of things with xpath but don't seem to be able to achieve quite what I want. I was wondering how you guys would go about it.

I tried (This works... but I don't want to be using the contains method for the 'name')

```
result = file.xpath("//prod[contains(.,\"Tour De France 2013\") and contains(.,\"Platform: XBOX 360\")]")[0]
# => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6e23c name="prod" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2b6e19c name="id" value="743854322">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6db84 name="pId" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b6d850 "GS811CF">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6d5d0 name="text" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6d300 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b6d094 "Tour De France 2013">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6ce14 name="desc" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b6cb1c "Platform: XBOX 360  Publisher: FOCUS HOME INTER  Genre: SPORTS  Supported Languages: English">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6c680 name="uri" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b70334 name="awTrack" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b70078 "http://www.awin1.com/pclick.php?p=743854322&a=161542&m=3026">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6fd94 name="awImage" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b6fb14 "http://images.productserve.com/preview/3026/743854322.jpg">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6f81c name="mLink" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b6f510 "http://tracking.searchmarketing.com/click.asp?aid=520005430000038657">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6f290 name="mImage" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b6efd4 "http://images2.drct2u.com/content/images/products/gs/gs811/gs811_xb2to52.jpg">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b6ebec name="price" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2b6eb74 name="curr" value="GBP">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b7256c name="buynow" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b72274 "47.00">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b71f7c name="delivery" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b71d10 "3.99">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b717d4 name="cat" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b7152c name="awCatId" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b7125c "579">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b70ff0 name="awCat" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b70d84 "Video Games">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b70a64 name="mCat" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b707bc "Main Menu|Electricals|Gaming &amp; Consoles|Video Games">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b742cc name="brand" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b73fd4 name="awBrandId" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b73d54 "427">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2b73a84 name="brandName" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x2b737c8 "Xbox 360">]>]>]>
```

So I then tried (returns nil):

```
result = file.xpath("//prod[contains(.,\"Platform: PS3\") and name = \Tour De France 2013\"]")[0]
#=> nil
```

I'm struggling to access 'name' - I think this could be because it's deeply nested. But I have no idea how to reference it.

Comment: You have tried lots of different things, apparently. So what are they? Show us exactly what you tried and explain why they didn't work (errors, etc). The start of any SO question is to put some code up there so we can *see* what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to give a little more detail above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following xpath to check for a prod node with specific text in the name and desc nodes:

```
'//prod[text/name="Tour De France 2013" and text/desc[contains(text(), "Platform: XBOX 360")]]'
```

For example:

```
file.at_xpath('//prod[text/name="Tour De France 2013" and text/desc[contains(text(), "Platform: XBOX 360")]]')['id']
#=> "743854322"
```

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the difference between .xpath and .at_xpath?

Comment: `.xpath` returns a node set of all matching nodes. `.at_xpath` will return the first node that matches. If you are only looking for 1 match, using `.at_xpath` is easier than doing `.xpath('path')[0]`. You can see the documentation - http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html.